# Spring Security SAML Extension - Load Balancer Support

Tags: spring-saml

According to the spring security SAML extension documentation, there are changes required to the spring context to make the extension work behind a load balancer (using reference guide here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/)

However, based on my testing (testing 2 servers behind an AWS ELB), the extension works as expected without the context changes in place. In what scenarios are these spring context changes required?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else has this question, you'll find that the SAML extension logs this warn message if you don't specify the entityBaseURL on the MetadataGenerator bean definition:

[WARN] [http-bio-8080-exec-5] [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter] Generated default entity base URL http://xxxxxxxx:80 based on values in the first server request. Please set property entityBaseURL on MetadataGenerator bean to fixate the value.

From what I can tell, it's not a requirement to use the load balancer specific bean, but the url used in SAML communication will be based on the url specified in the first request to your application. If you don't want this to happen, and want to get rid of that warning, you'll need to follow the directions in the SAML extension manual for setting it up for LB support.

Comment: can you please ellaborate? From what I understand, the LB url should be in the LB bean, and the entityBaseUrl should be what? also the LB url? Thanks.